# Verbal reading of 块?

Tags: grammar, mandarin, vocabulary

In my [open-source dictionary](https://chdict.zydeo.net/en/edit/existing/l66oa8L) a contributor has suggested a verbal reading for 块: to cut/chop into pieces, noting that in this 'verbal sense' it is always reduplicated. I cannot find this in either CC-CEDICT or ABC. In my corpus of movie subtitles I find 10 attestations of 块块 (see below), all of them preceded by 一, and often as 成一块块 or as 块块的.

I am asking for an analysis and suggestions. Does 一块块 belong in a dictionary as a headword? Should it be marked as an adverb, a complement ("into pieces"), or something else? Or, is there in fact a verbal reading of 块?

Attestations:

> 一块块的找
>
> 把躯体一块块进行肢解
>
> 哦,把他们砍成一块块?
>
> 要是再玩大男人的鬼把戏 我把你从头到脚一块块切下来
>
> 灰熊的领地被公路切分成一块块 使他们限制在很小的范围内
>
> 我要把你剁成一块块 交给吉迪恩，你这个淫妇！
>
> 唯见一块块血淋淋的你和我"
>
> 这里面一块块的
>
> 把她的脸割成一块块
>
> 还有一块块的

Comment: “一XX” is a very common pattern where X could be any measure word

Comment: This is a grammar topic, see e.g. CCG 2.10 Reduplication of measure words: measure words may often be reduplicated to mean plurality or exclusiveness. E.g.条条大路通罗马。个个都有责任。These reduplications may be preceded by the numeral 一 to mean "every" and may be used attributively like a "numeral + measure word" phrase:一朵朵花、一门门课程、一个个旅客。The attributive indicator 的 may also be included after the reduplication to mean "many": 一座座的桥、一台台的电脑。Reduplication of measure words together with their attached numeral 一，however, means "one after another":一个一个地（地 used to mark descriptive adverbials)\一步一步地、一口一口地。

Comment: This is very useful and I'd upvote as an answer, but I cannot do that for a comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's not a verbal reading of 块.

Second, 一块块 could be used as adjective, adverb or a complement, meaning 'into pieces' or 'pieces of'.

Examples(as an adjective， modifying a noun): 一块块肉，一块块面包，...

Examples(as an adverb， modifying a verb): 一块块地找，一块块地切下来，...

Examples(as a complement): "哦,把他们砍成一块块?", "灰熊的领地被公路切分成一块块";

Answer (score 1):

`一块块` is just short for `一块一块`

Try to speak very fast, `一块一块` just sounds like `一块块`

So there is nothing else about this. And like :

> 一种种，一个个，一份份，一点点，一句句

To many of them. Almost all words like `一...` can be said like this.